# Niftynet Data augmentation settings

Tags: niftynet

I'm using 'NiftyNet' for my project. For data augmentation, in the config file I noticed there are 'rotation_angle', 'scaling_percentage' and 'random_flipping_axes'. I checked the documents but still don't understand what is the proper setting for 'random_flipping_axes': if I want to flip all three axes, shall I use (1,1,1) or (0,1,2)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It should be 
random_flipping_axes=0,1,2

Based on the documentation here:
http://niftynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_spec.html?highlight=random_flipping_axes